# Windows programs slow down but anything else

Tags: windows-10, ssd, performance, task-manager, windows-10-v1703

So here is my strange problem: after a couple of minutes running servals programs like games and/or web browser, my computer seams to slow down windows applications like Explorer, Task Manager ect... But not my games or web browsers... My SSD where Windows is installed is running well (SMART said "Ok") and my second hard drive is the same. I've ressently upgrade my computer from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 (last update called "creator update" included) and I wonder if this could be the cause ?

Note: In the Task Manager (and ressource manager as well) the processor, the memory and every hard drives works like there is nothing.

Someone has an idea of what happend ?

Comment: Depending on what you're actually doing and what game you're running, you might happen to have "Game Mode" enabled. Another reason might be that the game is just so taxing on your machine that you're lacking resources.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I had no problems before updating my Windows. And when the game close (and all no-windows applications as well), thinks doesn't change and the only way to get Windows back to normal is to restart my computer...